# UMLシーケンス図の表記についてです

Tags: c#, uml

下記のC＃コードにおけるメソッドの場合、returnで値を返してメソッドから戻る記述方法を教えていただきたいです。 
この場合のシーケンス図の書き方は画像のような表記で良いのでしょうか？

```
public class Sample
{
    public bool IsZeroSecond()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Second == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: シーケンス図]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10187451750

Comment: `return DateTime.Now.Second == 0`って書きたいコード・・・

Answer (score 1):

シーケンス図では呼び出し元のオブジェクトも一緒に書くのが普通だと思います。
return で呼び出し元に値を返すので、左向きの点線で表現し 終端マークの黒丸は不要です。

opt の部分はあえて表現したいのかもしれませんが、このサンプルだと、無くても違和感無く感じます。省略する場合は、return の矢印を true と false でわけず 1本だけ引いて「return : bool」などの表現で十分伝わると思います。